# How do I set up the DN for a SSL cert with a hostname of greater than 64 characters?

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509

Everywhere I read says to have the server hostname in the commonName field and the subjectAltName field. The problem is that the hostname that I want to sign has greater than 64 characters. Therefore, the hostname wont fix in that field. I have seen sites such as [this](http://www.rapid7.com/vulndb/lookup/certificate-common-name-mismatch) which even say that it is a security vulnerability not to have the hostname as the commonName. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe answer is that the cname is only an alternate. The cname and the san dont have to match.

Answer (score 0):

Check this RFC:

- [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#appendix-A.1)

This previous questions at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com):

- [certificate-subject-x-509](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464129/certificate-subject-x-509)
- [what-strings-are-allowed-in-the-common-name-attribute-in-an-x-509-certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136198/what-strings-are-allowed-in-the-common-name-attribute-in-an-x-509-certificate)

As for a workaround, you can set a short [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) entry in your DNS.

Comment: That wont work: the reason being that the hostname is a sha2 hash, I cant shorten it without losing meaning.